# Most effective way to draw smooth animations over google maps?

Tags: google-maps, html, canvas, google-earth

I'm trying to draw an animation over google maps, hopefully using html5's canvas element. Is this possible? The animation is just along the lines of moving and rotating rectangles (simulating transit flows/traffic patterns), nothing fancy, but not something I see supported directly in the google maps API.

Are there alternative map API's that may support this? Would I be better off trying to do this in google earth instead?

I'm not much of a webgeek, so I apologize if this seems like an odd question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the HTML5 `<canvas>` element to draw and transform elements on top of Google Maps. You may want to check out the following Stack Overflow post for a short example showing how to rotate an icon on Google Maps using the `<canvas>` element:

- [Show wind direction on Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278534/wind-direction-show-on-google-map)