# How to calculate and show wind direction using Google Map API for a particular place?

Tags: php, javascript, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to find the wind direction for a place and show it on infowindow when people click on it using the Google Map API. How to actually find the direction?

Comment: related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278534/show-wind-direction-on-google-maps?rq=1

Comment: @Reflective I want to use it on API.

Comment: @Amitd it says I have already calculated wind direction. I want to know how to calculate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use api by [Weather Underground](http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/). It provides wind direction.