# Direction through arrow in Google Map

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, compass-geolocation

I am trying to show a wind direction on current location on google map with a circle and arrow as an [example](http://www.aviador.es/Statistics/Wind/VOBG-3) using ***html and javascript*** . I have a code which will display circle but not arrow.

I have gone through [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278534/show-wind-direction-on-google-maps)

but i am not getting the exact result. Can anyone help me on this issue.

Below is my **html** code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo">Click the button to get your position.</p>
<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>
<div id="mapholder"></div>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script>

var x = document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation() {
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError);
} else { 
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
 }
}

function showPosition(position) {
lat = position.coords.latitude;
lon = position.coords.longitude;
latlon = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon)
mapholder = document.getElementById('mapholder')
mapholder.style.height = '800px';
mapholder.style.width = '1600px';


var myOptions = {
center:latlon,zoom:14,
mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
mapTypeControl:false,
navigationControlOptions:{style:google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL}
}

 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapholder"), myOptions);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position:latlon,map:map,title:"You are here!",icon:"asd.png"});
// Define circle options
var circleOptions = {
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
    map: map,
    center: latlon,
    radius: 1000
};
var circleOptions1 = {
        strokeColor: '#FFFF00',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: '#FFFF00',
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
        map: map,
        center: latlon,
        radius: 500
    };
// Add the circle to the map.
var markerCircle = new google.maps.Circle(circleOptions);
var markerCircle1 = new google.maps.Circle(circleOptions1);

var dx=markerCircle1-markerCircle;
var dy=markerCircle1-markerCircle;
var radius=Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy)/2;
    $(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    ctx.translate(.5,.5);

    var img=new Image();
    img.crossOrigin="anonymous";
    img.onload=start;
    img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/sprite.png";

    function start(){

        var cw=canvas.width;
        var ch=canvas.height;

        ctx.drawImage(img,cw/2-img.width/2,ch/2-img.height/2);

        var data=ctx.getImageData(0,0,cw,ch).data;
        var leftX=getLeft(data,cw,ch);
        var rightX=getRight(data,cw,ch);
        var topY=getTop(data,cw,ch);
        var bottomY=getBottom(data,cw,ch);
        var w=rightX-leftX;
        var h=bottomY-topY;
        var cx=leftX+w/2;
        var cy=topY+h/2;
        var radius=Math.sqrt(w*w+h*h)/2;

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(leftX+w/2,topY+h/2,radius,0,Math.PI*2);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();

        ctx.strokeRect(leftX,topY,w,h);

    }

    function getLeft(data,width,height){
        for(var x=0;x<width;x++)
        for(var y=0;y<height;y++)
        {
            if(data[(width*y+x)*4+3]>0){ return(x); }
        }
    }

    function getRight(data,width,height){
        for(var x=width-1;x>=0;x--)
        for(var y=height-1;y>=0;y--)
        {
            if(data[(width*y+x)*4+3]>0){ return(x); }
        }
    }

    function getTop(data,width,height){
        for(var y=0;y<height;y++)
        for(var x=0;x<width;x++)
        {
            if(data[(width*y+x)*4+3]>0){ return(y); }
        }
    }

    function getBottom(data,width,height){
        for(var y=height-1;y>=0;y--)
        for(var x=width-1;x>=0;x--)
        {
            if(data[(width*y+x)*4+3]>0){ return(y); }
        }
    }


}); // end $(function(){});


}

function showError(error) {
switch(error.code) {
    case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
        x.innerHTML = "User denied the request for Geolocation."
        break;
    case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
        x.innerHTML = "Location information is unavailable."
        break;
    case error.TIMEOUT:
        x.innerHTML = "The request to get user location timed out."
        break;
    case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
        x.innerHTML = "An unknown error occurred."
        break;
    }
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not without seeing your code.

Comment: @mrupsidown I have edited and added running the code only with circle.

Comment: Please create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net). Your code doesn't work as it is.

Comment: just copy the code and create a ***.html*** file on your desktop and try it you will get the code working.

Answer (score 0):

I got solution for my problem and got the result with the below lines of code.

```
var start_point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);     
var end_point = new google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(start_point, 1000, 180);
```